# ASOP Cuttlefish clears userdata.img every time it starts

Tags: android-emulator, android-source, user-data

Why does asop cuttlefish clear the `userdata.img` every time it starts？Here is my console output:

[image: problem image]

I couldn't find the answer even after checking the Cuttlefish official website. Are there any issues with my cuttlefish?

[cuttlefish dpkg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJymA.png)

Comment: It looks like, before userdata.img is written, you have another error. Maybe fixing that will fix the issue that you are noticing?